# Creating a Input Char menu

Tags: java, char

[Coding a Ask for Char menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7iRP.png)

Trying to construct a menu in which allows a user to add or view parts from a linkedlist. Ive been following a tutors video, however when he enters In.nextChar his program works fine, however my program wont accept that as an option/method of obtaining the users input.

The code is exactly the same as the tutors but as you can see I get the error where return In.nextChar(); is

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add actual code to it, formatted with the `{}` button. In general, it's better to show your code than to describe it.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). StackOverflow is not a coding tutorial or free code site.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like an `ArrayList` as storage for your Parts.

```
public class Catalogue {

    private ArrayList<Part> parts;

    public Catalogue() {
        parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
    }

}
```

if you want to be able to add certain Parts to the Catalogue you can just add the the Part-Instances to the `ArrayList` by

```
Part myExamplePart = new Part(...);
parts.add(myExamplePart);
```